# Why do Bourbaki define the characteristic of a ring the way they do?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, definition

Here is the definition of the characteristic of a ring $R$ that is common in everyday usage (for example in Lang's *Algebra* and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_(algebra))): take the unique homomorphism
$$
\mathbb{Z} \to R
$$
and define $\operatorname{char}(R)$ to be the smallest nonnegative integer that generates the kernel of this map.

And yet on page [A.V.2](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=GXT1CAAAQBAJ&lpg=RA1-PA2&ots=BSrelV4FGm&dq=a%20ring%20with%20no%20subfield&pg=RA1-PA2#v=onepage&q&f=false) of Bourbaki's *Algebra II: Chapters 4 - 7* the characteristic is defined in a way that excludes rings without subrings which are fields. This leaves the ring of integers without a characteristic. While I can appreciate that $\mathbb{Z}$ is best considered as a *mixed characteristic* ring, what was the purpose of defining the characteristic like that?

Answer (score 7):

I can't speak to their motivation, but it seems that a little later on they remark that a quotient of a ring has the same characteristic as the original ring, which would be false if they allowed rings not containing fields.